# Finding rows based on condition

Tags: r

I'm new on R and am having some trouble on that specific query

I want to find the people that have type 1 before (order) having a type 2 (and they must have both types)

```
Person | type | order
A1     | 1    | 1
A1     | 1    | 2 
A2     | 2    | 3
A2     | 1    | 4
A2     | 2    | 5 
A3     | 1    | 6
A4     | 1    | 7
A4     | 2    | 8
A5     | 1    | 9
A5     | 1    | 10
A5     | 2    | 11
```

In this example I'd have `A4` and `A5` as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `flag` to identify the `Person` where `type == 1` occurs before `type == 2`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  summarise(flag = which.max(type == 1) < which.max(type == 2))

# Person     flag 
#  <fct>     <lgl>
#1  A1      FALSE
#2  A2      FALSE
#3  A3      FALSE
#4  A4      TRUE 
#5  A5      TRUE
```

---

Using the same logic with base R `aggregate`

```
df1 <- aggregate(type~Person, df, function(x) which.max(x == 1) < which.max(x == 2))

df1
# Person  type
#1 A1      FALSE
#2 A2      FALSE
#3 A3      FALSE
#4 A4       TRUE
#5 A5       TRUE
```

You could then subset `type` to get `People`

```
df1$Person[df1$type]
#[1] "A4"  "A5"
```

---

Another approach using base R `ave`

```
unique(df$Person[as.logical(with(df, 
   ave(type, Person, FUN = function(x) which.max(x == 1) < which.max(x == 2))))])
#[1] "A4" "A5"
```

Comment: thanks, i tried some weird stuff

i tried
T1 <- df[df$type==1,]
T2 <- df[df$type==2,]
to get the types separeted

colnames(T1)[colnames(T1)=="order"] <- "T1_order"
colnames(T2)[colnames(T2)=="order"] <- "T2_order"
to later join them

T1_T2 <- left_join(T1, T2, by = "person")

and finally

result <- T1_T2[T1_T2$T1_order<T1_T2$T2_order,]


buuuuut, i was losing some results and was very frustrated ._.

Comment: @FelipeTomazelliCrespo no problem, frustration is part of learning. I am glad you could figure it out in the end.